# Excel: get the value of third column on the behalf of second column

Tags: excel

i am not much familiar with excel formulas and i am trying to get the value of third column on the behalf of second column.
Example:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  A       B           C           D              E       |
|-----|----------|----------|--------------|--------------|
|Sr.No| Bar Code |  Cat Id  | Org BarCode  | Org Category |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  1  | 89457898 |          |   85214784   |      2       |
|  2  | 87414714 |          |   63247458   |      3       |
|  3  | 85214784 |          |   89457898   |      4       |
|  4  | 63247458 |          |     ----     |     ---      |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

i just want to update column `C` by column `E` on the behalf of column `D` and `B`

can any one please tell me the formula, how i can do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35676773/match-values-in-two-columns-and-return-value-using-vlookup-from-third-column-in?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Use `VLOOKUP`.  Enter the following formula into cell `C1` and then copy it down the `C` column:

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, D$1:E$4, 2, FALSE)
```

To cover more than 4 rows, then just update the formula accordingly.  If you want to display a certain placeholder value if a value in column `B` be not found, then you wrap the call to `VLOOKUP` as follows:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(B1, D$1:E$4, 2, FALSE), "Not found")
```

Comment: what is `4, 2` ?? because we have 300 to 400 records where we have to find the bar code

Comment: Did you actually try my answer?  Read [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php) to see how `VLOOKUP` works.

Comment: its always say not found

Comment: I suspect that you made a mistake somewhere; this formula should work.

Comment: Column `L` stand for `E` and `M` stands for `D` and `C` stands for `B`

Comment: I'm not in front of a computer at the moment, sorry.  Maybe someone else can look at the spreadsheet.  I don't think the answer will change though.

Comment: i thinks its working..some times its showing `#REF!`  what it means?

Comment: There may not be a match for every barcode in column `B`.  If you expect this, you can wrap the call to `VLOOKUP` in `IFNA` to display a more user friendly message.